# How fast is elasticsearch counting?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, count

Theoretically, you can build data structures (like sets or maps) so for a given key you can know the number of occurrences in constant time.

I'm wondering if this is the case for Elasticsearch [count query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html).

Is it constant to count for a single-field indexed query (assuming that the amount of shards is constant...)?

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I am using elasticsearch from last 18 Months and worked on various usecases in ElasticSearch. We have around 1+ Billion documents and each document size is more than 10KB. We are also storing the data on various nodes so  we have multiple shards of every index. Still for this much volume of Data elastic Aggregations are super fast. Generally they provide the result very fast.

But mostly You do not need to call count Api as elastic search returns total  number of results found with every query. Still if you just need the count then you ca use it.

Avg time of Getting the Aggregation results in elastic search in our case was around 300 ms.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but this isn't what I am asking. The main reason behind using count query instead of regular queries is to get the count as fast as possible without having an impact in the database, thus either it can answer in constant time or it can actually count how many there are.

Comment: So as per my knowledge you can also do the query in count api and elasticsearch perform the count function in every shard on the basis of that query. if you do not provide the query then it will be same as match_all in elastic.